# Convert Set of Tuples to a List of Lists | Python

Tags: python, list, set, tuples, python-itertools

Generating unique combinations by using `set()` over `itertools`.

Outputs a set of tuples, each originating from their invocations respectively.

Instead, I now want to convert this result into a list.

```
import itertools

my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
pairs = set(itertools.combinations(my_list, 2))
print(pairs)
>>> {('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'B')}
```

Instead, I would like:

```
[['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a built-in function for creating lists, one that you are likely to need here. If the elements in the list are distinct, it is pointless to invoke `set` on the results of itertools. Just use a simple list comprehension directly on the itertools output.

Comment: Yes, but have failed. I also have seen very many posts that are similar to this one but not quite this problem. Since set() and itertools are commonly used together, I thought this Q&A would be a great resource for others to copy from.

Comment: what have you tried exactly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga list comprehension for loops; this was my ideal.

Comment: `[list(i) for i in itertools.combinations(my_list, 2)]` to just skip the undesired container in the first place and just go straight to lists

Comment: @CoryKramer Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a =[[item for item in pair] for pair in pairs]
print(a)
```

returns

```
[['B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```